# Добавление записей в google sheets при помощи php

Tags: php, google-spreadsheet

Кто знаком с api google sheets, не могли бы подсказать, что не так с данным кодом? Выдает ошибку в последней строке кода. Просьба не кидать ссылки на документацию. Спасибо!

```
$range = 'A1';
$spreadsheetId = '1vH3VkRoD3NIyuzxjl-eO8EnNLFbS32pvn2ztahSQ';
$values = [
    [
        'Какой-то текст'
    ],
];
$body = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([
  'values' => $values
]);
$body->majorDimension = 'ROWS'
$params = [
  'valueInputOption' => 'RAW'
];
$result = $service->spreadsheets_values->append($spreadsheetId, $range,$body,$params);
```

Comment: Что за ошибку выдает? И чему равняется переменная $service?

Comment: @user209681
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
пытался вывести через print_r $result,ничего не вывело.
Тестил код для вывода из таблицы - всё работает.

Comment: Используйте для вывода ошибок. ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: @user209681 
https://pp.userapi.com/c848416/v848416877/f55a/tMnEh2X2sgU.jpg
в ссылке изображение,так как ошибка превышает кол-во символов

Comment: define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
    Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS,
    Google_Service_Sheets::DRIVE,
    Google_Service_Sheets::DRIVE_FILE) 
)); Попробуй добавить это

Comment: @user209681 Та же ошибка, к сожалению(
Scopes был равен Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS_READONLY